# Ignore SIGINT in Java

Tags: java, posix

I'm using a Java wrapper for a native shared library on Unix ([JRI](http://www.rforge.net/JRI/)).  The native library (a C based REPL implementation for R) handles SIGINT internally.  When using the Java wrapper, the Java application quits when I send a SIGINT to the process using:

kill -SIGINT pid

I'd prefer for the SIGINT to be entirely handled by the native library internally.

Is there an easy way to make Java completely ignore a SIGINT but still have the native library receive it?

**Addition:**

Preferably this would work on Unix and OSX.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no standard API for it, but if you are using the Sun JDK, you can use [`sun.misc.Signal`](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/misc/Signal.html) and [`sun.misc.SignalHandler`](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/misc/SignalHandler.html).
Example from the docs:

```
SignalHandler handler = new SignalHandler () {
    public void handle(Signal sig) {
        ... // handle SIGINT
    }
};
Signal.handle(new Signal("INT"), handler);
```

Comment: Know any way to get this to work on OSX?  I don't seem to have access to sun.misc.

Comment: This should work fine on all operating systems, that is not the problem.
If you don't have those, maybe you are using a different JDK? See the output of "java -version"