# nohup process dies on xterm close but not on exit

Tags: linux, bash, putty, strace, nohup

I have an issue where a simple nohup command seems to be behaving oddly.  I have boiled this down to a small java app named Sleep that does a

```
while (true) 
  Thread.sleep(10000).
```

I'm running nohup as follows:

```
nohup java Sleep.java >> nohup.log 2>&1 &
```

I then run strace in another window looking for signals as follows looking for my pid (12345)

```
strace -tt -p 12345 -enone -e 'signal=!sigchld'
Process 16582 attached - interrupt to quit
```

If in my original window i type 'exit' to close the shell I see the process continue to run without getting a signal.  However if i close the putty window (click x on the menu bar) i see that the nohup'd process does get a SIGHUP

```
strace -tt -p 16582 -enone -e 'signal=!sigchld'
Process 16582 attached - interrupt to quit
14:54:03.271286 --- SIGINT (Interrupt) @ 0 (0) ---
```

I thought nohup was supposed to intercept/not pass down the SIGHUP.  I've since switched to using setsid and i get the correct behavior no matter how i close the terminal window.  Am i doing something wrong?  It seems like nohup isn't quite working correctly which is causing some serious problems in the real issue I'm working on.

Comment: Closing the putty window seems to trigger a SIGINT (rather than SIGHUP), which `nohup` can't/doesn't catch.

Comment: There seems to be too much detail here.  You're saying that if you ssh into a box, run a long-running process like `nohup sleep 10000 &` and then terminate your ssh connection by closing the client, that the "sleep" process is being terminated?  That definitely doesn't sound right.  I just tested and it works fine on my boxes.  (Maybe chepner is right, and putty is generating a bad signal.  In which case that sounds like a bug in putty).

Answer (score 0):

On dealing with this in Java...  Note that although the thread suggests that this'll work on any OS, I doubt Windows has signals:
[Ignore SIGINT in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250280/ignore-sigint-in-java)

You could also write your own nohup-equivalent that ignores SIGHUP and SIGINT.  Or you could download the GNU nohup source and modify it to ignore SIGINT too.

For once, this probably isn't a windows/putty problem.